# Swift Showing last sent message in chat using firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to show my last sent message on my home screen of the chat messenger, from storyboard it looks like :
[image]

and the code I used are:

```
func getAllMsg() {
    self.users = []
    let fromId = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("privateMessages").child(fromId)

    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        for snap in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            // retrieving receiver's ID
            let chatUserID = snap.key

            let ref2 = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(chatUserID)

            // to retrieve message ID
            ref2.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot2) in
                let newUser = User(dictionary: snapshot2.value as! [String: AnyObject])
            // to get the last message
            ref.child(chatUserID).queryLimited(toLast: 1).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot3) in

                let value = snapshot3.children

                while let rest = value.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {
                    newUser.lastMessage = (rest.value as! [String: AnyObject])["textMessages"] as? String

                    self.users.append(newUser)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    break
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I have done some changes to my database and the above codes works, but after i changed the way i do my database, it doesnt work anymore
previously, my firebase looks like

[image]

now my firebase looks like:
[image]

i made a chatRoomId by using send and receiver ID. however I am now not able to show my last sent message which was supposed to show on my homescreen. Any ways I can go about this? Or the way I fetched my database is wrong?

Comment: Don't use query in loop. Just go to the `chatRoomId` and perform `.queryLimited(toLast: 1)`. This should be perform individually not in side the loop.

Comment: I think my code is a bit messy, i went to message database, get the key...then to user database, then get the last message...confusing...any codes above i should delete?

Comment: You just need a single query for this. Code just below `// to get the last message` line you have written. `chatRoomIdRef.isEqualTo(userId).queryLimited(toLast: 1)` something like this.

Comment: didnt get it.. Do u have any reference I can look up on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is wrong according to your db structure. Also don't perform `lastMessage` query inside the block of other query because this is totally independent query and not related with any. Below piece of code will work for you.

```
let ref = kFirDefaultDatabase.reference().child("yourChatRoomId").queryOrdered(byChild: "fromId").queryEqual(toValue: "0YfqnPIOYFYKb8cYZMHnSYti62i2").queryLimited(toLast: 1)
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value) { (snapshot) in
     if snapshot.exists() {
        print(snapshot.value)
     }
}
```

This will fetch the last message sent by `fromId` for the requested `chatRoomId`. For more detail have a look at [Firebase Queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query) doc.

And if you want to do this in table for all users like in `WhatsApp` or other chatting application then you will need to make an extra table `LastMessages` and save last message information here corresponding to each `chatRoomId` or if possible save this detail somewhere you can fetch with the `tableData` so that you don't need to query for each `chatRoom` in a loop.

You can do some better stuff to make it faster. Use `CoreData` or `Sqlite` and save/update `lastMessage` information into `local db` whenever you send or received any message, where `chatRoomId` will be a `primary key` and first get the information from `local db` and show in the `table` immediately and mean while you can fetch the data from server and update your `local db` and refresh the `table`.

**EDIT:** For comment *`to get the last message regardless I send to recipient or recipient send to me`.*

Remove `orderBy` query and just use `limitToLast`. See below code:

```
let ref = kFirDefaultDatabase.reference().child("yourChatRoomId").queryLimited(toLast: 1)
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value) { (snapshot) in
     if snapshot.exists() {
         print(snapshot.value)
     }
}
```

Comment: I have asked a new question, will be clearer there. Couldnt delete this question.. it's at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50169921/swift-fetching-data-from-firebase

Comment: @WilliamLoke Leave that new question as it is, Here you have got the answer so try it.

Comment: Instead of asking new question for same problem is not good. Try editing the existing question with more information and coding stuff is always better for you, answerer and the community.

Comment: i have deleted that new one, one moment. let me try do this code u posted

Comment: Please read my full answer rather than just code. It will help you.

Comment: understand, your code is to fetch the last message sent by fromID,yes? if i were to get the last message sent regardless if it's sent by fromID or toID, i just delete the fromID child away?

Comment: What do you mean by `i just delete the fromID child away`? You don't need to delete anything for this purpose.

Comment: I have finally done it using the code u typed, queryOrdered(byChild"fromID")queryEqual("0YfqnPIOYFYKb8cYZMHnSYti62i2") but it's only able to fetch the last msg I sent to the receipient. What should I add, so that it's able to fetch the last message regardless if I send to recipient or receipient sent to me?

Comment: @WilliamLoke See **EDIT** part of the answer.

Comment: yes, i tried using this but this will allow all users to see ALL the messages from the databases including other user's message

Comment: `"yourChatRoomId"` is specific for chatRoom so this should not be the case if two people are chatting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up rooms differently.

If you you have 3 people in a room, what will the RoomID be ? If someone leaves the room how will you know what the room history is ?

Comment: hmm...that would be for group chats, yea? noted...Maybe for group chats, I will set AutoID for each rooms, like how I did for PrivateMessage-MessageID? thx for heads up on there