# Getting timestamp from firebase in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to get my timestamp from firebase and convert it to our normal time of hh:mm: a and I have done:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: PrivateMsgMainMenuTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! PrivateMsgMainMenuTableViewCell

        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("privateMessages")

        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded) { (snapshot) in
            for rest in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {

                let messageID = rest.key

                let ref2 = Database.database().reference().child("privateMessages").child(messageID).queryLimited(toLast: 1)
                ref2.observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value) { (snap) in
                    let messageDetails = snap.children

                    while let timeSent = messageDetails.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {
                        let timeSentDetails = (timeSent.value as! [String: AnyObject])["timestamp"] as? Double

                        let converted = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timeSentDetails! / 1000)

                        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                        dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
                        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
                        let time = dateFormatter.string(from: converted as Date)

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            cell.timeLabel.text = time
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
    }
    return cell
}
```

my firebase looks like: 
[image]

i am trying to retrieve the last sent message's time and show up in a label in my tableview, but am unsure why it doesnt show up and the code after

```
let timeSentDetails = (timeSent.value as! [String: AnyObject])["timestamp"] as? Double
```

doesnt run when I put a break point. is there any mistakes I've done here?

Comment: does it prints timestamp on console after getting from firebase?

Comment: nope, the code skipped everything after let timeSentDetails = (timeSent.value as! [String: AnyObject])["timestamp"] as? Double

Comment: just print the timeSent.value before using. and tell us the result.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to fetch the last message. You really need to read the Firebase doc how it actually works. Although what I told you in your last questions you are even not following that.

Comment: @TheTiger the previous question, I have managed to solve them using your code. Now this code is to fetch the last msg and am using the same logic as previous, but it doesnt work

Comment: @MRizwan33 cant, the code at timeSent, doesnt run

Comment: then @TheTiger is right u r not fetching last message correctly.

Comment: `cellForRowAt` calls multiple time do you know? `.childAdded` event call multiple times do you know? You're queering in a `for loop` and then enumerating an array in `while loop` these are multiple too. So how does your code fetch only a `lastMessage`?

Comment: do u have any reference I am able to look at? I kinda partially understand what you meant..Sorry @TheTiger, you been a big help but still a newbie, tq for your patience

Comment: I understand! But [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50167629/1140335) already describes how to fetch last message. See you need to make sure that not to query for same data again. Here you have to show the `lastMessage` in table, Do not fetch in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` instead fetch in `viewDidLoad` one by one and just reload the table as you get the data. Read my answer carefully.

Comment: ok, what u meant is, create a variable in a class file, lets say message.timestamp...then once i fetched it in viewdidload, use cell.timelabel.text = message.timestamp in my cellforRow...correct?

Comment: Yes Exactly! Also your query should be neat and clean so that once per `chatRoom` so  `numberOfQueries = numberOfChatRooms`.

Comment: done it! finished the work! great help, @TheTiger